# Cancel key down, press, up event in PHP javascript, C#

Tags: javascript, c#, php, jquery, dom-events

I want to cancel out key press event when my textarea field gets **n** number of characters from user. At that point I don't want user to enter any more characters. What to do?

**Edit:**

I need it to be done in Javascript as well as in PHP.

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? Which version?

Comment: @John: I want to know this for Asp.net, winform, php, javascript. Right now i need it for Php and javascript both.

Answer (score 1):

In web pages, **NobleCount** is one possibility.  Seems to be the most robust of the jQuery plugin solutions.  It will give your user a count of the number of characters remaining, Twitter-style.

http://tpgblog.com/noblecount/

See also:

**Interactive character limit for textarea using Jquery**
http://www.ajaxray.com/blog/2007/11/09/interactive-character-limit-for-textarea-using-jquery/

Answer (score 0):

In Winforms, you would set `Handled` in the `KeyPressEventArgs` to `true` to cancel the `KeyPress` event. This keeps the control from processing the key press.

Note: 
Some controls will process certain key strokes on `KeyDown`. For example, RichTextBox processes the Enter key before KeyPress is called. In such cases, you cannot cancel the `KeyPress` event, and must cancel the key stroke from `KeyDown` instead.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keypresseventargs.aspx

Comment: @Robert: I could have accepted your answer, but Question was not the one you answered for. I was trying to cancel javascript event.

Comment: OK, but your comment said you wanted it for Winforms also.